# Java EE Bean inject into another Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans, cdi

I'm making two beans say ABean and BBean. I want to inject BBean into ABean but this is causing null pointer errors, likely because the bean has yet to be instantiated. How can I inject beans in beans as such:

```
@Singleton
public class ABean {

  @Inject
  BBean bean;

  ....

}
```

I'm using java ee 7 with wildfly server. Both beans are singletons so BBean is also declared as:

```
public class BBean {

  @PostConstruct
  public void startup() {
    ..
  }

  ..
}
```

With out the dependency, I'm able to create both beans as I do have the necessary META-INF folder and beans.xml file with in it. I'm however coming to the conclusion that this might be bad practice/ anti-pattern. Anyway I'm not using this approach anymore.

Comment: How are you creating ABean?

Comment: What app server are you using?

Comment: There's a bunch of things that could cause this. How does beans.xml look? Which version of java EE or more precisely of CDI are you using etc. 
We have to little to work with here to help you.

Comment: Typical issue is using the injected bean inside the constructor. You need to wait until after constructor is called, e.g. use a `@PostConstruct` method. Also make injected beans private as exposing them may require lots more overhead/limitations.

Comment: In your example above you don't have BBean's class annotated with a scope. If that's really the case thats your problem.

Comment: Do injection points work correctly elsewhere in your application and have a problem  only in this situation injecting a singleton bean into another singleton bean?

Comment: Yes, they work else where

Comment: Is `BBean` precisely decorated by `@Singleton` in your real code? (I am repeating the other's comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to add the beans.xml file, in order to enable CDI in your application. This is what the Java EE 6 Tutorial says http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html:

> An application that uses CDI must have a file named beans.xml. The file can be completely empty (it has content only in certain limited situations), but it must be present. For a web application, the beans.xml file must be in the WEB-INF directory. For EJB modules or JAR files, the beans.xml file must be in the META-INF directory.

Comment: If it is Java EE 7 (which is unclear from the question), `beans.xml` is not a mandatory requirement to enable CDI.

Answer (score -1):

did you remember to include a setter so the bean can be injected?  @Inject does not work like @EJB.

also, like previously indicated, do not try to use the bean until after the owning bean is instantiated (not in constructor, only in @PostConstruct'ed method)

hope that helps.

Comment: setters are not used with CDI.

Comment: since when?  you can only omit them if you use constructor injection.

Comment: That's not true at all.  Where did you learn that?  Setter injection is only used when it's annotated.  Field injection is the preferred approach.